# Pig CPU intensive task - small data file - many mappers?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm looking for any tips on how I can improve performance with my Pig job.

The input is a single file (MB), but for each line in the file a very CPU intensive task is executed.

So the ideal would be to split this file across many mappers (and machines) within my Amazon EMR cluster.

However I can't find a way to do this, as Hadoop will naturally only split at 64 (or is it 128?) MB intervals, so I only ever have 1 mapper!

I have looked at NLineInputFormat (http://www.olenick.com/blog/hadoop-for-small-data/), but this is for the old API, and also not sure how this works with Pig.

To complicate things further, I am loading using the CSVExcelStorage piggybank loadfunc.

Thanks

Duncan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

This needed a few more parameters set.  I'm not saying that you need to set ALL of these, but I didn't have the time to do the trial and error to see what is the minimum required set.  More than happy to be corrected on this!

Put the following at the top of your pig script:

```
SET mapred.max.split.size 131072; -- 128KB
SET mapred.min.split.size 131072;
SET default_parallel 2;
SET pig.noSplitCombination true; 
SET mapred.max.jobs.per.node 1;
```

I've set mine to 128KB blocks, as my input is really that small!

In addition, set the dfs block size.  In Amazon EMR, do this by setting the following Boostrap action:

```
--hdfs-key-value dfs.block.size=131072
```

We can see that this has worked by looking at the output:

Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   **Maps**    Reduces MaxMapTime  MinMapTIme  AvgMapTime  MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime    Alias   Feature Outputs
job_201309111450_0001   **14**  0   15  9   11  12  0   0   0   0   A,cleansed,nostop   MAP_ONLY    s3n://mybucket/out42,

So we can see that 14 mappers were used.  Also there were 14 parts generated (in my case) and the total run time was the same amount of time as per a single record (4 minutes in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping your input splits as small as possible.  Set this property:

```
SET mapred.max.split.size  1000; -- or whatever
```

The number is split size in bytes.  If you have a 30 MB file and want 3000 mappers (for instance), try setting the maximum split size to `10000`.

Comment: Thanks.  A stupid question - does this go in the pig script?  The configuration?  I am using Amazon EMR, configuration is available through bootstrap actions only I think - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

Comment: I have not used Amazon EMR, but that line is meant for the Pig script.  You can also set options like that with the `-D` command line flag, but that seems even less likely to work.  If there is a way for you to check on the configuration of the submitted hadoop job (can you see the JobTracker?), you can verify if the property has taken effect there.

Comment: Thanks Winnie, it needed some extra options set (setting the split size alone didn't work) so have documented this in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a detailed solution, just a general idea...

You can solve this by executing your UDF in the reduce phase (instead of the map phase) and use PIG's parallel features that let you control the number of reducers. To give you a hint, you can set the script's default number of reducers (to 40 as an example) with this:

SET default_parallel 40;

One way of forcing your UDF to run in the reducer is by doing a GROUP and then calling the UDF passing each group.

E.g.

ag = GROUP a BY x PARALLEL 40;
b = FOREACH ag GENERATE yourUdf(a);

A group requires a sort phase, so the FOREACH after the group will run in the reducer.

You could try GROUP a ALL if you don't have a good key to choose, it will likely work. Also, you need to change your UDF to take in a DataBag instead of a tuple or a scalar because each group is passed as a bag. It may be a bit tricky to implement but once done it is quite simple and elegant.

If you already have a GROUP in your script you may be able to use that one and save the extra map-reduce job. There are other clauses that also force a reduce phase that you might want to consider.

David